# Diagram, 4 dots. (knot theorem)

Tags: diagrams

How to drow this in teXstudio? I cant draw dots and arrows like that

[image: cyrcle with 4 points]

Comment: Hmm, the fact that you got an answer when you posted your previous question of that type (and with the same title) should not make you conclude that this is the way to ask questions here. You got an answer, and you may either try to understand it or tell the answerer what's missing, but please refrain from going on like this.

Comment: again please use a sensible question title, also this is unrelated to texstudio (that is just the editor you are using to write the file) and unrelated to math mode (as you have tagged it)

Comment: is  it okey now ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a `just-do-it-for-me` question.

Answer (score 1):

I made this and my previous answer a community wiki to allow others to change or delete it if they feel it is inappropriate to answer such questions.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,bending}
\begin{document}
 \begin{tikzpicture}[bullet/.style={circle,fill,inner sep=1pt}]
  \begin{scope}[local bounding box=stuff]
  \path foreach \Y in {1,2,3,4}
   {(225-\Y*90:1) node[bullet,label=above:$P_\Y$] (B\Y){}};
   \draw[thick,-stealth,shorten >=2pt,shorten <=2pt] 
    (B1) edge[bend left] (B2) (B2) edge[bend left] (B1); 
  \end{scope}
  \node[circle,draw,fit=(stuff)]{};
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]